# How to get a php session variable and use it in the where clause at ssp to get a single ligne record with datatable

Tags: php, mysql, datatables

I spend hours on searching for a solution to filter table and show only the ligne recordes where column equal the value of session variable for that i try this:

> i called only one variable session into the server-response.php on head of file :  require_once("./_inc/config.php") and i have stocked this session variable to a second variablea as next: $CodeApogee = $_SESSION["code_apogee"];
>    and this variable i used it as condition in the $sWhere clause as next :

```
       /* 
        * Script:    DataTables server-side script for PHP and MySQL
        * Copyright: 2012 - John Becker, Beckersoft, Inc.
        * Filtering
        * NOTE this does not match the built-in DataTables filtering which does it      
        * word by word on any field. It's possible to do here, but concerned about efficiency
        * on very large tables, and MySQL's regex functionality is very limited
        */
        $CodeApogee = $_SESSION['code_apogee']; //changes

        $sWhere = "notes.code_apogee=".$CodeApogee." ";
        if ( isset($_GET['sSearch']) && $_GET['sSearch'] != "" ) {
            $sWhere = "WHERE (notes.code_apogee=".$CodeApogee.")"; //changes
            for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($columns) ; $i++ ) {
                if ( isset($_GET['bSearchable_'.$i]) && $_GET['bSearchable_'.$i] == "true" ) {
                    $sWhere .= "`".$columns[$i]."` LIKE :search OR ";
                }
            }
            $sWhere = substr_replace( $sWhere, "", -3 );
            $sWhere .= ')';
        }
```

**_
and my data.php file look like:_**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#note').dataTable( {
 "aProcessing": true,
 "aServerSide": true,
 "ordering": false,
 "searching": true,
 "paging":   true,
 responsive: true,
 "ajax": { 
    url: "server-response.php",
    type: 'POST'
}
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body class="note">
<table id="note" class="display responsive table table-striped table-hover dt-responsive" cellspacing="0" width="100%"> 
<thead>
<tr>
<th class="all" >Code Apogee</th>
<th class="min-phone-l" >Nom</th>
<th class="min-phone-l">Prenom</th>
```

Also the datatable style wont run like i configure it.

[Retrieve Session from php and use in DataTable as query variable](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/20895/retrieve-session-from-php-and-use-in-datatable-as-query-variable)
Please help me i hav read this post and i cant figure out how to do the same,

Here's the firebug screenshot one record has been filtred out but no data comes with from the table.
[image]

Comment: I dont see a `session_start();` anywhere? Do you have one in ALL code that uses the `$_SESSION` array

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Firstly,** Make sure that, you used session_start() in both page from where you setting a value in session and where you used in this session variable.

**Secondly,** change this

```
$CodeApogee = $_SESSION['code_apogee'];
 to 
$CodeApogee =  "'".$_SESSION['code_apogee']. "'";
```

Comment: it's already called in the config.php file and it's work fine without re-initiation, but same server msg {"iTotalRecords":"280","iTotalDisplayRecords":"1","aaData":[]}  !! anyway for tha second clarification for also that first used works, thank you ...

Comment: If you want to thank me please click on upvote button. Thank you.